# PHP SDK for PayPal RESTful APIs going live error

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, sdk

I am currently trying to switch from sandbox mode to live for the payment system I have created. This is the first time I have used the paypal sdk so I am not all that familiar with it. I keep receiving the following error once I reach the point of the system where you should be redirected to paypal. I know this question has been asked before I looked through all of those, tried their changes but it is still not working for me.

[Error when trying to get to paypal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmynC.png)

When in sandbox mode it works perfect, I changed the credentials to the live credentials.

This is the beginning of my system where it should authorize the system

```
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('SITE_URL', 'url name');
$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
 new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
 'Client ID',
 'Secret Code'
 )

);
```

Here is my sdk_config.ini file it is in the same folder that my code is in:

```
;Account credentials from developer portal
[Account]
acct1.ClientId = 
acct1.ClientSecret =
;acct2.ClientId = TestClientId
;acct2.ClientSecret = TestClientSecret

;Connection Information
[Http]
http.ConnectionTimeOut = 60
http.Retry = 1
;http.Proxy=http://[username:password]@hostname[:port][/path]

mode=live

;Service Configuration
[Service]
;service.EndPoint="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"
; Uncomment this line for integrating with the live endpoint 
 service.EndPoint="https://api.paypal.com"


;Logging Information
[Log]
log.LogEnabled=true

; When using a relative path, the log file is created
; relative to the .php file that is the entry point
; for this request. You can also provide an absolute
; path here
log.FileName=PayPal.log

; Logging level can be one of FINE, INFO, WARN or ERROR
; Logging is most verbose in the 'FINE' level and
; decreases as you proceed towards ERROR
log.LogLevel=FINE

;Validation Configuration
[validation]
; If validation is set to strict, the PayPalModel would make sure that
; there are proper accessors (Getters and Setters) for each model
; objects. Accepted value is
; 'log'     : logs the error message to logger only (default)
; 'strict'  : throws a php notice message
; 'disable' : disable the validation
validation.level=strict
```

I am not sure what is being missed, could someone please point me in the correct direction to fix this. Also, within paypal's developer site, under the actual app where you click the live button, I click the live button I have my code using those credentials. I click save when it says live but when I go back, it goes back to sandbox.
Please let me know if you need additional code provided to reach the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message "invalid_client" , it looks like you still use the wrong client id and secret, or maybe use the live credential in sandbox environment. As you mentioned, in sandbox environment, it works fine, so there is no issue in your code. 
If you copy the live client id and secret correctly, please double check your code, maybe there is a setting in other file that need to configured as live environment.